# Java String Comparison with html tags

Tags: java

I have two Strings as follow:

```
String input="<tr><td>Hello world</td></tr>";
String output="<body><tr><td>Hello world</td></tr></body>";
```

I want to compare the two strings and need to remove the `<body></body>` tags from the output string if the input string doesn't contain `<body>` tag. The string may be of any length.

How to compare and replace the output string based on input string?
`<body>` tag may be anything like `<body ></body > or < body>< /body>,etc`.

Need to find the tag and replace it based on input string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static String[] combinations = new String[] {
    "<body>","</body>","< body>","< /body>","<body >"
};

for (int i = 0; i < combinations.length; i++) {
    if (!input.contains(combinations[i])) {  
        output = output.replace(combinations[i], "");    
    }    
}
```

Comment: if input string doesn't contain <body>, probably you meant *!input.contains..*

Comment: also you are discarding the result of replace

Comment: <body> tag be like <body > </body > in that case your condition will fail rite..?

Comment: @user1321824 I noticed that but the OP wrote: if the input string doesn't contain <body> tag. this got me abit confused... ill mention this as a comment.

Comment: @O.D :) the question in the comment comes from the OP actually.

Answer (score 1):

```
 String resultingOutput = "";
 if( !(input.contains("<body>")) && !(input.contains("</body>")) ){
      resultingOutput = output.replace("<body>", "").replace("</body>","");
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int compare;
if (!input.contains("<body>"))
compare = output.replaceAll("<body>","").replaceAll("</body>","").compareTo(input);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Practice {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "<tr><td>Hello world</td></tr>";
    String output = "<body><tr><td>Hello world</td></tr></body>";
    String tag = "<body>";
    String replace = "";

    System.out.println("Output : " + validate(input, output, tag, replace));

}

private static String validate(String input, String output, String word,
        String replace) {

    if (!(input.contains(word)) && !(input.contains(word))) {
        output = output.replace(word, replace).replace(word, replace);
    }
    return output;

}}
```

Comment: although the code itself is correct, output wont ever actually change on the outside of the method, strings are immutable